# Angular2: How to inject service that has no decorators to the app?

Tags: angular

When trying to use `Http` in the App component (the component we are bootstrapping) everything works find:

```
export default class AppComponent {

  constructor(public http: Http){
    console.log(this.http);
  }

  getData() { 

  }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

But if I wrap Http with a `CustomHttpService` (and ofcouse add CustomHttpService to the bootstrap componenets array):

**custom-http-service.ts:**

```
export default class CustomHttpService {

  constructor(public http: Http){
    console.log(this.http);
  }

  getData() { 

  }
}
```

**app.ts**:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [CustomehttpService]);
```

I'm getting:

```
NoAnnotationError {message: "Cannot resolve all parameters for CustomHttpServic…ake sure they all have valid type or annotations.", stack: $
## _onError ##
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at angular2.dev.js:19620
    at Zone.run (angular2.dev.js:138)
    at Zone.run (angular2.dev.js:10644)
    at NgZone.run (angular2.dev.js:10607)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (angular2.dev.js:19615)
    at Object.commonBootstrap (angular2.dev.js:26650)
    at Object.bootstrap (angular2.dev.js:27475)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.ts:23)
    at app.ts:23
    at SystemJSLoader.__exec (system.src.js:1384)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

What am I missing? Isn't that enough to import modules and register the custom service in the bootstrap function?

This question is relevant to every class that has no metadata (Component, View etc.. ) we want to inject to our application.

Comment: You should read this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html), explains exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: @EricMartinez. This is perfect !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Eric Martinez comment and [this awesome explanation](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) I could see that the typescript types are not enough when no meta-data is attached to the class (with decorators).

The fix proposed in this article is to  add metadata to the class we want to inject (in my case this is the `CustomHttpService`) and this will become:

```
@Injectable() // from angluar2/core
export default class CustomHttpService {

  constructor(public http: Http){
    console.log(this.http);
  }

  getData() { 

  }
}
```

and of course to add the service to the injectables array in the bootstrap function:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, CustomHttpService]);
```

and now it works.