# When injecting(importing) a service into my constructor I get a "No provider" error

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 2 - When injecting(importing) a service into my constructor I get a "No provider" error.

**Here's my service I'm importing:**

```
 export class EnvironmentService {

   public baseurl: string = "/baseurl/example/";  

 }
```

**Here's my class with the error:**

```
import {Http, Headers} from "angular2/http";
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {EnvironmentService} from './environmentService';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

    constructor(private _environmentService: EnvironmentService) {

        //This is where the error is.
        console.log(this._environmentService);

    }

    isUserLoggedIn = (): Promise<boolean> => {   

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           resolve(true);
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm unsure why the environment service isn't injecting

Comment: Your service has no decorators. This might be the root cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486392/angular2-how-to-inject-service-that-has-no-decorators-to-the-app

Answer (score 1):

Add `AuthService` in `app.module.ts` **Providers**

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't specify `EnvironmentService` as a provider for your application. You can do it by passing all providers in a second argument of the [`bootstrap`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/application_common.ts#L221) function, or using [`providers`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L665) and [`viewProviders`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L873) properties of the `Component` decorator:

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [EnvironmentService /*, other providers */]);

// or

@Component({
    // ... component config
    providers: [EnvironmentService],
    // or
    viewProviders: [EnvironmentService]
})
class AppComponent { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Would this still work because I'm not in the app component. I'm in a different component

Comment: I've tried putting the "EnvironmentService" in several places like you've said above.

Answer (score 0):

GO to the module that you want to use the `EnvironmentService` i.e `app.module.ts` or other modules.

after imports
you will see provider as an array
add the EnvironmentService

```
providers: [AuthService]
```